# How to find frequency of dates in R

Tags: r, date, frequency

I have a fishing dataset containing dates for when a catch was made, when the ship put the catch into port and the ID of the boats. As an added problem i have several datapoints for the same day as each boat has delivered several classes of fish.

I am trying to find the length of trip by taking the day of catch minus the day they last put into port. And i have to separate it by boat and make sure that it only counts one landing per day.

This is my data, LandingD is date of landing, FangstD is date of catch and SkipID is ship ID

```
    LandingD    FangstD   SkipID
1   2000-02-19 2000-02-19   0004
2   2000-02-16 2000-02-16   0004
3   2000-04-29 2000-04-29   0004
4   2000-04-29 2000-04-29   0004
5   2000-11-30 2000-11-30  0020B
6   2000-02-16 2000-02-16  0075H
7   2000-02-16 2000-02-16  0075H
8   2000-01-22 2000-01-22  0075H
9   2000-01-15 2000-01-15  0075H
10  2000-01-29 2000-01-29  0075H
11  2000-02-11 2000-02-11  0075H
12  2000-02-04 2000-02-04  0075H
13  2000-06-02 2000-06-02   0076
14  2000-06-02 2000-06-02   0076
15  2000-05-20 2000-05-20   0076
16  2000-03-21 2000-03-21   0087
17  2000-03-21 2000-03-21   0087
18  2000-02-24 2000-02-24   0087
19  2000-02-24 2000-02-24   0087
20  2000-11-27 2000-11-27   0087
```

Any idea how this could be solved?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it intended that `LandingD` is always the same as `FangstD`?

Comment: Can you show what your desired output would look like and also please share the sample data (using `dput`).

Comment: It is not intended that they are allways the same, hopefully there is some variation there!

Comment: I am hoping for output in the form of number of days between landingd, tried usinf dput but that created a hot mess. The dataset contains 8'000'000 rows...